# Ratio Of UVs after unwrap

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

When I unwrap the object I am working on, the UV are way out of proportion. You can see in the image attached that the bottom piece is relatively small compared to the rest yet it takes up a majority of the UV space while the rest of the object is way too small. I have been looking through other questions asked on Stack Exchange.

So far, scaling the object has not worked. Turning on correct aspect ratio has not worked, projecting from view is a no go, nothing is working. Smart UV unwrap doesn't work. I have tried using add-ons but I am not getting any progress with those either.[image]

Is there a way to get this thing to scale properly?

Comment: Have you tried selecting all UVs and using the "average islands scale" tool? Unwrapping only affects the selected faces, so they won't be able to control other UVs

Comment: I tried it just now, does not work. Maybe I am using it wrong? How do i use Average Islands?

Comment: maybe you wish to use that tool for what it has not been thought for, it seems you wish to unfold your model... not to map a texture on it

Comment: Do you have answers or comments?

Comment: It is unwrapped going to mirror the sides. Want to check for distortion.

Comment: Are you sure that you have not pinned them?

Comment: Did you apply scale for the model? (Object mode > Ctrl+A) See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7967/1245 for example. If something doesn't work like expected add some details about what *exactly* didn't work and what did you try.

Comment: I followed the link you posted. When I got clear the Scale of the model (Object -> Clear -> Scale) the model becomes deformed as i I had manually set everything back to (1,1,1), Is there a way to reset the Scale so the model ratio can be set at (1,1,1) without this happening?

Comment: Got it! I think. Found the apply tool in the same info site as the clear Tool. Much appreciated I have been having issues with this for days. Thank you again.